# Using a comparison table. Mobile responsive problem when more than one table added?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

The comparison table I am using is here:

https://codepen.io/adrianjacob/pen/KdVLXY

When I duplicate the tables and the viewer goes mobile responsive; the buttons are only working for the first table.

Is there any classes or such I can add to the JavaScript and HTML so I can make each group of buttons specific to their table?

Button code:

```
<ul>
  <li class="bg-purple">
    <button>Self-Employed</button>
 </li>
  <li class="bg-blue">
    <button>Simple Start</button>
  </li>
  <li class="bg-blue active">
    <button>Essentials</button>
  </li>
  <li class="bg-blue">
    <button>Plus</button>
  </li>
```

JavaScript code:

```
// DIRTY Responsive pricing table JS

$( "ul" ).on( "click", "li", function() {
  var pos = $(this).index()+2;
  $("tr").find('td:not(:eq(0))').hide();
  $('td:nth-child('+pos+')').css('display','table-cell');
  $("tr").find('th:not(:eq(0))').hide();
  $('li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});

// Initialize the media query
  var mediaQuery = window.matchMedia('(min-width: 640px)');

  // Add a listen event
  mediaQuery.addListener(doSomething);

  // Function to do something with the media query
  function doSomething(mediaQuery) {    
    if (mediaQuery.matches) {
      $('.sep').attr('colspan',5);
    } else {
      $('.sep').attr('colspan',2);
    }
  }

  // On load
  doSomething(mediaQuery);
```

I'd really appreciate any help, thanks for your time.

Comment: yes, you can add the different class to each `ul` and releated `tables` and based on that you can change your jquery.

Comment: Hi Chilll, Thanks for your comment.

I did try this however the buttons were changing the cells on every table instead of the one specified.

I've spent a good few days on this to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your jQuery targets are currently too generic, so when you have multiples, it only finds content from the first one and puts it in both.  What your script does is update *both* tables.

I've forked the Codepen, added a second table, and tweaked a couple of values on our comparison table, so you should see different things in each (and each set of tabs acts separately)

https://codepen.io/CapnHammered/pen/QzBbqN

Key part you're missing is some form of parent selector - in this case, we've used an `article` tag to wrap our table:

```
$( "ul" ).on("click", "li", function() {
  var pos = $(this).index()+2;
  $parent = $(this).closest('article');
  $parent.find("tr").find('td:not(:eq(0))').hide();
  $parent.find('td:nth-child('+pos+')').css('display','table-cell');
  $parent.find("tr").find('th:not(:eq(0))').hide();
  $parent.find('li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("ul").on("click", "li", function(e) {
  var $clicked = $(e.currentTarget); // This will give you the clicked <li>
  var $ul = $clicked.parent();
  var $table = $ul.next(); // Only works if the table immediately follows the <ul>
  var pos = $clicked.index() + 2;

  $table.find("tr").find("td:not(:eq(0))").hide();
  $table.find("td:nth-child(" + pos + ")").css("display", "table-cell");
  $table.find("tr").find("th:not(:eq(0))").hide();
  $clicked.siblings().removeClass("active");
  $clicked.addClass("active");
});
```

Basically, when you click a `<li>` you should search the next table and show/hide the information only on that table. Before you were selecting all `<tr>` elements so it would affect all tables in the page.

EDIT: after re-reading your question this sentence left me confused:

> When I duplicate the tables and the viewer goes mobile responsive; the buttons are only working for the first table.

When I try to duplicate the tables in your codepen the buttons work for both tables, not sure if I'm understanding your problem.